# What is the correct syntax for package.json for local server with google cloud platform?

Tags: json, http, server, cloud, platform

I am trying to use google cloud platform to Build, Secure, and Protect a Web Application. I am trying to follow Google's instructions to get everything setup and I am on this document: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/building-app/writing-web-service

On this part:
Running the server locally
To run the server locally:
Run **npm start** in your terminal. This will run your **server.js** file.

However, everytime I do that, I get this error:
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32\my-nodejs-service> npm start
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! path C:\Windows\System32\my-nodejs-service/package.json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Expected ',' or '}' after property value in JSON at position 52 while parsing '{
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "dependencies": {
npm ERR! JSON.parse     "express": "^4'
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse JSON data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse Note: package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

So I keep trying to alter the syntax of the JSON file but its not working.

Right now my syntax is this:
`{ "dependencies": { "express": "^4.16.3" }  { "scripts": { "start": "node server.js" }`

the server file is called server.js... I have no idea what the issue is...

I have spent 2 hours trying to web search this and I have to move on. Does anyone know what exactly the syntax is supposed to be for this file?

I have tried numerous changed to the syntax of the package.json file.
When it runs, it should rumn my run your server.js file and then I should be able to point my browser to http://localhost:8080 and should see a page with the text "Hello from App Engine!"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  }
}
```